# How to Convert .csv into .txt for Matlab Import

Tags: vba, excel

I have a .csv file. I want to convert it into .txt file starting from line the A to the B (A, B are declared at the beginning). The .txt file supposed to have gaps " " instead of original semicolons. Moreover, the end of each copied row from the original .csv file should be indicated by a semicolon in the new .txt file (txt file is going to be used as an input matrix for Matlab).

That's what I have till now, but it's not working

```
   Sub csv2mat()
        Dim Filename As String
        Dim Filenamenew As String
        'Change the path to the Files and and create a txt file
        Filename = "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\as.csv"
        Filenamenew = "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\new.txt"
        Open Filenamenew For Output As #2
        Open Filenamme For Input As #1
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, str
            str = Replace(str, ";", """")
            Print #2, str
        Loop   
        End Sub
```

Comment: @detall ok thank you. I added the code

Comment: Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, watch VBA start complaining about typos.

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks for the tipp. I will include this

Comment: @Mat'sMug how do this work with the FreeFile function? And thanks for the Tipps with the Close function

Comment: `Dim handle1 As Long, handle2 As Long`, then `handle1 = FreeFile` and `handle2 = FreeFile` - and then you `Open Filename For Input As #handle1` and you can `Close #handle1` (`Close` without a file handle closes all open files).

Comment: @Mat'sMug nice to know, thanks for the tipp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hade a few spelling mistakes like Filnemme with to m.
And you forgot to close the Files after Reading.
And you didn't add the ";" ad the and of the string if i understand you right

Try this:

```
Sub csv2mat()
        Dim Filename As String
        Dim Filenamenew As String
        Dim str As String
        'Change the path to the Files and and create a txt file
        Filename = "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\as.csv"
        Filenamenew = "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\new.txt"
        Open Filenamenew For Output As #2
        Open Filename For Input As #1
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, str
            str = Replace(str, ";", """") & ";"
            Print #2, str
        Loop
        Close #1
        Close #2
        End Sub
```